# In Datatable Excel Export Zero Value is Coming wrong in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, excel, datatable

I am exporting excel sheet from datatable Using plugins. In the sheet all values Are coming correctly except zero (0) values.

Here is the code for datatable.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
                     //"scrollY": 300,
                     //"scrollX": true
                      dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                         { extend: 'excelHtml5', text: 'Get Excel' }
                    ],
                      "sScrollY" : "300",
                      "sScrollX" : true,
                      "bScrollCollapse" : true,
                      "bSort" : true,
                      "iDisplayLength": 5


                     });
```

I have attached the screen shot of the error.[image]

Comment: you need to check the export code of plugin and need to do modification there. also other values are treated as number except 0? is it?

Comment: How to know whether other values are treated as number or string. And Can you please help me with what modifications I need to do in plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the CSV button instead of the xcel button and it works fine:
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html

Either

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );
} )
```

or for a more personalised approach (assuming font-awesome, and applying a little CSS to make it look a little nicer)

```
    //initialise the main table
table = $('#report').DataTable( {
    "bFilter": true,
      "bSort": true,
      "bInfo": true,
      "scrollX": scrollX,
    lengthChange: true,
    fixedHeader: {
        header: true,
        footer: footerFixed
    },
    buttons: [ 
        {
            extend: 'copy',
            text: '<i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>',
            titleAttr: 'Copy'
        },
        {
            extend: 'csv',
            text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
            titleAttr: 'CSV',
            title: 'Subscribers'
        },
        {
            extend: 'colvis',
            text:      '<i class="fa fa-columns"></i>',
            titleAttr: 'Columns'
        },

    ],
} );

table.buttons().container()
    .appendTo( '#report_length' );

$('#report_length > label').css('padding-right', '10px');
```

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case link gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your plugins to set the field type to a number value.

Looks like 0 is being interpreted as string, which could explain the left alignment.

Comment: How to use plugin to set the field type to a number value. Can you explain please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some modification in buttons.html5.min.js file.
Find that word excelHtml5  in buttons.html5.min.js and in push method
"number" === typeof a[c] || a[c].match && g.trim(a[c]).match(/^-?\d+(.\d+)?$/) && **"0"** !== a[c].charAt(0)
replace **"0"** to **0** 
or another way just add one condition 
 !== (a[c].charAt(0)&&a[c].length>1)
it will work .Hope it will fulfil your requirement.
All the best..!!